# JPA left join queries wont instantiate child collections in Spring Boot?

Tags: jpa, spring-boot, java-8, spring-data

Just a quick question, I am using JPA with spring boot. I have a class Member with a @ManyToMany(FetchType.LAZY) relationship to class Artist. Members does not have to have Artists but Artists needs to have Members.

In my **JpaRepository** extension I have a method for fetching Members and any possible Artist children it may have. Looks like this:

```
@Query("select m from Member m left join fetch m.artists where m.id=:id")
Member getMemberWithArtists(@Param("id") long memberId);
```

In the case where A has no B children the B collection comes back as null. 
I was using this approach with a JavaEE project before and then this kind of query would always give me an empty collection instead of just NULL. Is spring boot handling this differently?

My question is, is there anything I can do so that it returns an empty collection instead of null?

**Here is Entity A**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="MEMBER")
public class Member extends LocationHolder implements Messenger {

    @ManyToMany(cascade={CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.REFRESH}, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name="MEMBER_ARTIST_REL", 
       joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="MEMBER_ID", referencedColumnName="ENTITY_ID"), 
       inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="ARTIST_ID", referencedColumnName="ENTITY_ID"))
    private List<Artist> artists;
```

**Here is B**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="ARTIST")
public class Artist extends LocationHolder {

   @ManyToMany(mappedBy="artists", targetEntity=Member.class, fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade={MERGE, REFRESH})
   private List<Member> members;
```

@Id field is in the superclass and is of type Long

Comment: Seems to be weird, could you please also post the code of the classes `A` and `B`.

Comment: Just edited the question with full class names

Comment: Just tried with exact your classes, and empty set was returned instead of `null`. However, there is one question though, do you execute the query in the same JPA session where the `Member` was created (eg, in the integration test) ? If yes, could you please post the code which includes your test ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default JPA should indeed return an empty set in the scenario you have described. However, looking at your entities I suspect that there is a scenario which could lead to the `null` result :

1. It looks like that your entities do not initialize the `artists` list to an empty collection when an member is created.
2. Create and save an instance of a `Member`
3. If in the **same JPA session** you would try to load the `member` using `getMemberWithArtists` repository method then, indeed, the `member.artists` collection would have been `null`. This is caused by the fact that the `member` instance is returned from the JPA session cache (the one created in the step (2) where `member.artists` was equal to `null` due to missing default initialization of the collection)

I have tried to illustrate same in the code snippet bellow :

```
    @Test
    public void testNullCollection() {
            Member member = new Member();
            memberRepository.save(member);
            member = memberRepository.getMemberWithArtists(member.getId());
            // Here the collection is going to be null since the instance is returned from the session cache
            assertNull(member.getArtists());
            entityManager.flush();
            entityManager.clear();
            // Here the collection is going to be empty, since in the previous step the session was cleared hence forcing JPA to initialize the entity from scratch and inject lazy collection
            member = memberRepository.getMemberWithArtists(member.getId());
            assertNotNull(member.getArtists());
            assertTrue(member.getArtists().isEmpty());
        }
```

This integration test actually passes for me. (in case of test JPA session spans for the whole test. In the actual web application you should configure the JPA session to last only for a single request).

I believe that just initializing the `member.artists` to an empty collection in the constructor of the `Member` entity should solve the issue for the newly created and persisted entities (when loaded within the **same JPA session**).

```
    public Member() {
        this.artists = new ArrayList();
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your help Ruben, initializing the collections solved the issue. However, is this a good thing to do? I made a decision early not to initialize the collections thinking it would lead to a bunch of wasted allocated memory. Isn't it better to only initialize them when it is needed? Or am I being overambitious here? I don't have a whole lot of knowledge with JPA so please let me know.

Comment: You are welcome :-).  Well, to be honest I would not bother too much for the extra memory unless you have strict requirements on it. However, what you could also do is postponing the initialization of the collection till it is actually accessed (deferred initialization), eg, add a `null` check and default initialization routine in the `getArtists()` method. As long as all accesses of the collection go through `getArtists()` you can enjoy both benefits : rest of the application is not aware that collection might be `null`; you do not waste memory till the collection is accessed.

Comment: Ok good to know, i'll go for that approach then. thanks for taking the time to help!